# Mockito Scala overloaded method value thenReturn with alternatives

Tags: java, scala, types, mockito

I am new to Scala and am writing some tests for Play app in Scala. The Play app has already been written in Java.

I have a RefreshService that has one public method process

```
public RefreshResponse process(RefreshRequest request) throws Exception {
    return this.oauthService.token(request.oauthUrl, request.clientId, request.clientSecret, request.refreshToken)
        .thenCompose(oauthToken -> this.processHelper(request.withOAuthToken(oauthToken)))
        .get();
}
```

Where actions are defined in another package as a POJOs

I have written my tests based on the Scala guides

When trying to mock this service I used the following code

```
var mockRefreshService = mock[RefreshService]
when(mockRefreshService.process(_: RefreshRequest)) 
    thenReturn (new RefreshResponse)
```

I get the following compiler error from Scala and cannot figure out how the types can be ambigous

> [error] /home/joey/Projects/sntdb/test/controllers/ApiControllerSpec.scala:31: overloaded method value thenReturn with alternatives:
>
> [error]   (x$1: actions.RefreshRequest => actions.RefreshResponse,x$2: actions.RefreshRequest => actions.RefreshResponse*)org.mockito.stubbing.OngoingStubbing[actions.RefreshRequest => actions.RefreshResponse]
>
> [error]   (x$1: actions.RefreshRequest => actions.RefreshResponse)org.mockito.stubbing.OngoingStubbing[actions.RefreshRequest => actions.RefreshResponse]
>
> [error]  cannot be applied to (actions.RefreshResponse)
>
> [error]             when(mockRefreshService.process(_: RefreshRequest)) thenReturn (new RefreshResponse)

If anymore information is needed please let me know. Otherwise if anyone has any ideas it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `mockito-scala` you can mix-in the trait `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchersSugar` and it will provide all the appropriate ones, furthermore, for `any` you don't need to specify the type anymore as the compiler will figure it out

Check https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala for more info

Disclaimer: I develop that library (but is part of the mockito suite anyway)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this, but would love some insight into why this worked.

I replaced _: RefreshRequest with any[RefreshRequest] I understand this I think.

But the imports have me tripped up.

I imported

```
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any
```

and thats when everything worked

when I imported

```
import org.mockito.Matchers.any
```

I got a error

```
value any is not a member of org.mockito.Matchers.any
```

Looking at the docs for Matchers it is a subclass of Argument Matchers so how did it not have any?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the only thing that helped me is to extract parameter into variable. For some reason it worked:

```scala
var mockRefreshService = mock[RefreshService]
val response = new RefreshResponse
when(mockRefreshService.process(_: RefreshRequest)) 
    thenReturn(response)
```